# How to config tmux so that new windows reuse working directory of last window?

Tags: tmux

When I open new window or new pane in a `tmux` session, the directory is always where I started the session.

More often than not, I'm expecting the new windows or new panes to be in the working directory of the pane I switched from.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

See this answer in the Unix stack exchange:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12032/create-new-window-with-current-directory-in-tmux

In short, the newer version of tmux no longer defaults to opening a new window in $PWD ... you'll now be able to set this in your .tmux.conf, or on the command line.